# Как сделать так, чтобы у определенного товара новости не выводились?

Tags: битрикс

Есть каталог электротовары. Соответственно в электротоварах есть, например, товар "дрели". Когда кликаем по товару "дрели" изменить, то в самом низу у меня есть привязка к новостям. Когда я выбираю какую-то определенную новость из предложенных, выводится, как и надо - одна новость. Но если я выбираю "нет", то почему-то выводятся все новости. Как и где мне это править?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами то программист? Если нет то сами тут наврятли чего-то сделаете.
Если да. То смотрите в сторону фильтров для компонентов. Ибо вы код не выложили и не понятно ничего. То что у вас в админке вообще всё равно.
Скорее всего перед новостным компонентом объявлена глобальная переменная.
Например global $arFilter; $arFilter=array('ID'=>$idFilter);
$idFilter - может называться по другому. Содержит в себе ID новостей для вывода. Если пустая, то нет и фильтра, стало быть, выводятся все новости.
Самое простое решение это просто повесить if условие, что если нет привязанного ID то не выводить компонент новостей вообще.

Comment: Спасибо, что натолкнули, разобрался.